# How does conversion from string to char array work in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I just started learning C++ and I was trying to output a string through printf.
It wouldn't work because I had to convert the string into a char array first.
I googled it and it seems that the best solution was this:

```
char *a = &b[0];
```

I somewhat understand it: It's getting a reference to the first character and setting a to that.
The part that I don't understand is that this only makes sense to me if the string is stored on the stack, which I know it sometimes can be. If the string is on the heap, what exactly will the [0] index return? Does it return the pointer to the first index, because then the & isn't necessary is it? If it returns the character, doesn't that character take the form of a single value on the stack, which, when referenced, wouldn't give you the correct char array?

Comment: Who says that's the best solution and not the [c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method?

Comment: On a side note, you should not be using `printf` in C++, use `cout` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I heard printf is faster. I've also seen someone look at the generated binary and there are way fewer instructions in printf. If printf is faster, I don't really see a reason not to use it.

Comment: @NikTedig `printf()` may be faster than `cout` (and that is debatable, it depends on the kind of formatting being performed), but that speed is in part due to `printf()` not being safer than `cout`. It is much more prone to user errors for the sake of performance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What kind of user errors?

Comment: @NikTedig type mismatches, incorrect buffer sizes, etc between the format string and the input values being formatted. `cout` is much more type-safe in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to note is that `operator[]` returns a *reference*.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

> **reference operator[]( size_type pos );**
>
> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos.

This is important because it means that `b[0]` is essentially an alias to the first character in the string. Taking its address will then give you a pointer to the underlying buffer the string's data is stored in. It doesn't matter where it is (stack, heap, etc). This is also what lets you modify the string's data by using e.g. `b[0] = 'a';`.

Note that you can also use [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) and [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) to get a pointer to the first character in the string. Since C++17 `data()` can return a non-const pointer.

Comment: The OP is trying to pass a string to `printf()`, `c_str()` and the const `data()` will work fine for that.

Comment: @Kevin Alright, I think I get it now. I think I was confused because of the lack of an asterisk, which to my knowledge is used to set the value behind a pointer in C++. It makes sense that the asterisk isn't needed for an array though. Thx.